# Why am I experiencing a buffer error?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I had an error from debugging with the "delete" instruction, and I'm not able to know why. When should I use delete?

below you can see the code:

```
int GenerateOrderData(SetupData &mySetupData, OrderData &myOrder, int Level, wchar_t *buffer, bool normalAOC, int theActualCutsinPlatform)
{
    int Size = 0;

    if ( buffer != NULL )
    {
    //INIT
    wchar_t* lString = new wchar_t[3];
    swprintf(lString, L"%s", L"LPD");
    Size += swprintf(buffer+Size, L"%c%02d%s", Communication::UNICODE_STX, numMSG, lString);
    delete[] lString;
...}
```

And the error from the debugger:

> Debug Error!
>        HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#152) at 0x00806F80. CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after
>   end of heap buffer.

The thing I'm not understanding is how can I get a buffer error with an array I create and after deallocate with delete.

Comment: You must `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. If you don't allocate memory using `new` or `new[]`, you shouldn't be doing `delete` or `delete[]`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn about the SO model. I suggest you read [ask] to better understand what can be improved in your question. Focus on the section that explains how your post should contain a [mcve].

Comment: And if you get crashes, then you need [to learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically you need to learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash "in action", to help you locate when and where it happens in your code, and also to let you examine variables and their values at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, strings are terminated by zero. So `L"LPD"` is actually characters `L, P, D, \0`. You need to use `new wchar_t[4]` to have space for the terminating null character.